# inner join CSV values in string format to MySQL table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of email addresses that I need to verify against a DNC table. Fairly simple in theory- ready for the twist? I cannot make a temp table. Nor do I wish to issue a SELECT statement for each email. Wouldn't it be unsightly to chain 'OR' statements? I would imagine relatively inefficient. Anyone see a clean, efficient way of going about this?

Comment: ...WHERE email IN ('some@email.com', 'another@email.com', 'athird@email.com');

Comment: @theTaiko: submit that as an answer so all the votes can give you rep

Comment: @invertedSpear - thanks.  I didn't originally submit it as an answer because I'm not entirely sure what the OP intends to do with the results.  But it does solve chained OR statements...answer added below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can use "IN" instead of chaining a bunch of "OR" statements.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE email IN ('some@email.com', 'another@email.com', 'athird@email.com');
```

is a much easier way of writing:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE (email = 'some@email.com'
   OR email = 'another@email.com'
   OR email = 'athird@email.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = '
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE email IN ("'.implode('","', $yourArray).'")
';
```